# Manners of eating!

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

What is the adverb describing best a person who is eating food with no care how much he drops on the table, how badly he is taking eatables out of the dishes lying on the table, how much he leaves things half-eaten, and who is eating a lot in one single move. He is moving from one item to another as if it is going to vanish in a moment.

> 1. He is eating carelessly.

> 2. He is eating voraciously.

> 3. He is eating badly.

> 4. He is making a panic-eating.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "manners of eating" is not idiomatic - it sounds like *ways* of eating. The kind of etiquette you are referring to is called "table manners".

You want to describe someone who is leaving a mess all over the table, but none of your suggested choices really mean this:

- He is eating carelessly <- this could mean not taking care about food choices.
- He is eating voraciously <- this just means eating a lot, or heartily.
- He is eating badly <- this also means eating bad food choices, such as junk food.
- He is making a panic-eating <- this isn't idiomatic at all.

The most idiomatic term for the kind of person you describe is "**a messy eater**", for example:

> He is such a messy eater!

If you must use it as an adverb you could say "he is eating *messily*".

Comment: Or, more formally "He is eating with no regard for good manners".

Comment: I would call a person like that a [slovenly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slovenly) eater. This is a word my father used a great deal when I was small. Also we can say the the person has poor, or no, [table manners](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/table-manners)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "slovenly" is primarily used to refer to a person's own appearance - it would be an odd choice to describe the mess made on the table.

Comment: Shows English usage, although a [Scots dictionary](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/sloch_v2_n2): _slocher, a slovenly messy eater, one who makes loud noises when eating or drinking, a noisy slobbering way of taking food_

Comment: "Somehow – I am not usually a slovenly eater – I managed to spill scrambled eggs onto my trousers, which improved my Savile Row suit not at all." [blog](http://www.bownsbest.com/lapostavecchia.html)

Comment: "He was ludicrously overweight, a slovenly eater who dunked bread in his cocoa cup." [The Public Intellectual: Between Philosophy and Politics
edited by Arthur M. Melzer, Jerry Weinberger, M. Richard Zinman, Michigan State University, 2003.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EQUcUlKSARAC&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=%22a+slovenly+eater%22&source=bl&ots=tcEk3qJZmK&sig=ACfU3U1NGsACrEZRK2RA3Z-tRdimHpvlew&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZgIKEy6nrAhWtWhUIHSsIAKYQ6AEwHHoECBcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20slovenly%20eater%22&f=false)

Comment: We are talking, according to the OP, about the eater, not the mess.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey One of your examples talks about getting food on their clothes. Another uses "messy" *and* "slovenly" - the person was slovenly *and* a messy eater. Have a look at this ngram which compares instances of 'messy eater' with 'slovenly eater' in literature: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slovenly+eater%2C+messy+eater&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmessy%20eater%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmessy%20eater%3B%2Cc0